# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' bundle.js line 1 Docker container error

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, webpack

I'm learning Docker online using a tutorial. The only thing I was asked to build was the Dockerfile, so I'm sure the problem lies there, but I'm unable yet to figure out an effective way to debug the problem.

The problem is when I run the container with the built docker image index.html renders in localhost but bundle.js does not render and gives the error from the title in the console. When I webpack bundle on my local machine and open the index.html the webpage renders correctly.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.15-alpine as build-stage
COPY . /app
RUN npm install && npm start

FROM nginx:1.15
EXPOSE  80
COPY --from=build-stage /app /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "todos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This README would normally document whatever steps are necessary to get the application up and running.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --mode=development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './frontend/todo_redux.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react']
          }
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", "*"]
  }
};
```

nginx.conf

```
# This will tell our nginx server what path
# we want it to use for the html it renders
server {
  # list on port 80
  listen 80;
  location / {
    # to learn more about location blocks check out this resouce:
    # https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/#location-blocks
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Update: removed the CMD line I had in my node build portion of the Dockerfile, changed `RUN npm install` to `RUN npm install && npm start` and now bundle.js file is being created and added to nginx, but same error persists.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using locally? Your Dockerfile is referencing a pretty old version of Node, and I'm curious if the issue is in the Node version your Dockerfile is building the container with.

Comment: Pretty sure the docker config COPY command requires `<dest>` to end with a `/` if it is a directory copy. (`/usr/share/nginx/html` --> `/usr/share/nginx/html/`)

Comment: v14.13.0 They do mention that in the tutorial always try to use the same version. @KevinCodes

Comment: @RandyCasburn has a very good point. I would give that a try.

Here are the docs for reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: @JohnO'Brien can you try getting into your Docker container and looking at your index.html and bundle.js files?

`docker exec -it <your-container-name> sh` This command will give you an interactive terminal into the container, and from there just use the `cat` command. We are checking to see that the files look like they were copied over appropriately during container build.

Comment: @KevinCodes<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: @KevinCodes cat bundle.js just automatically gives me bundle.js.map

Comment: @KevinCodes So far ending ```/usr/share/nginx/html``` with ```/``` has no change.

Comment: @KevinCodes Is it better to go down to an older version of npm or just bring the Dockerfile image of node up to where I'm at?

Comment: @JohnO'Brien I would try upgrading node in dockerfile first, unless there is a specific reason you need that old version.

Comment: @KevinCodes Upgrading node didn't work. Here's a question, does this path from my image ```ENV``` look correct? ```PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin``` I keep wondering if this may be the reason that my webpack.config isn't ouputting bundle.js to the correct place...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228603/discussion-between-kevin-codes-and-john-obrien).

Answer (score 0):

Alright so finally got an assist from the makers of the tutorial and found out that I needed to create a `WORKDIR /app` and then copy into that. The below change to the Dockerfile fixes the problem:

```
FROM node:14.15-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && npm start
```

I was misreading the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), I thought that only using `COPY. /app` would create `/app` if it didn't find it, but it seems in terms of a multi-stage build that this isn't sufficient, and that `WORKDIR` needs to be created to be referenced properly by `--from=build-stage`. After that of course remember to `COPY . .` and not `COPY . /app` which is where I was stuck for a while as well. It seems to create an extra path `/app/app` within the image that messes up the final render.

Lastly the change from `node:8.15-alpine` to `node:14.15-alpine` seems to not have been a factor, it was an upgrade I did while debugging just to see if it was causing the problem.